# Missing comma error for some reason in SQL developer. Worked fine before

Tags: sql, oracle

I leave it to work on something else, which it was working alright before. Now it wont even run because of a missing comma error, even though the comma is already there

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID  NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR( 25) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20),
    HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    SALARY NUMBER(8,2),
    COMISSION_PCT NUMBER(2,2),
    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6),
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4)
);

CREATE TABLE job_history
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    START_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    END_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4)
);

--Question 1
INSERT INTO employees (EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)  
VALUES(176, 'Taylor', 'jasontaylor@gmail.com', '1999-AUG-31, 'SA_REP', 80);

INSERT INTO employees (EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)  
VALUES(200, 'Whalen', 'justinwhalen@gmail.com', DATE '1993-06-18', 'AD_ASST', 200);

SELECT LAST_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID, END_DATE, JOB_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID 
FROM employees;
NATURAL JOIN job_history;
```

Comment: '1999-AUG-31,    please close the date with '

Comment: There's also an extra semicolon: `FROM employees; NATURAL JOIN job_history;`

Comment: .....I think I might a few screws loose or something. Thanks

Comment: Only in SQL Developer?

Comment: It is really weird to see questions like "missing right parenthesis" or "missing comma" when the embedded syntax highlighting is already showing the place of error. Did you try to follow this guide: [How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? When you try to minimize it, you'll easily resolve the issue by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that comma is missing, but the whole date value in the first insert statement is wrong.

This: `'1999-AUG-31` is *nothing*, not even a string (missing trailing single quote). But, it isn't a valid date value either. Compare it to the 2nd statement which contains date literal: `DATE '1999-08-31'` (and yes, that's what you should be doing in the 1st statement as well).

When fixed:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO employees (EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
  2  VALUES(176, 'Taylor', 'jasontaylor@gmail.com', DATE '1999-08-31', 'SA_REP', 80);
                                                    -----------------
1 row created.                                      this was wrong

SQL> INSERT INTO employees (EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
  2  VALUES(200, 'Whalen', 'justinwhalen@gmail.com', DATE '1993-06-18', 'AD_ASST', 200);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

As of your **natural join** problems: natural join implicitly joins common columns (they have the same name) in both tables.

It means that your query:

```
SQL> SELECT LAST_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID, END_DATE, JOB_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID  FROM employees NATURAL JOIN job_history;

LAST_NAME                 DEPARTMENT_ID END_DATE   JOB_ID     EMPLOYEE_ID
------------------------- ------------- ---------- ---------- -----------
Taylor                               80 06-12-0031 SA_REP             176
```

returns the same result as inner join, joining common columns:

```
SQL> select e.last_name, e.department_id, h.end_Date, e.job_id, e.employee_id
  2  from employees e join job_history h on h.employee_id   = e.employee_id
  3                                     and h.job_id        = e.job_id
  4                                     and h.department_id = e.department_id;

LAST_NAME                 DEPARTMENT_ID END_DATE   JOB_ID     EMPLOYEE_ID
------------------------- ------------- ---------- ---------- -----------
Taylor                               80 06-12-0031 SA_REP             176

SQL>
```

If you wanted the query to return "more" rows, well, they should have matching data in those common columns. For example, although `EMPLOYEE_ID` values match, there's no `AD_ASST` job value in `job_history` table nor `department_id` whose value is `200`.

---

Data you need to return both employees: remove employee 200 and re-enter it with modified job and department data; then your NATURAL JOIN works.

```
SQL> delete from job_history where employee_id = 200;

1 row deleted.

SQL> INSERT INTO job_history (EMPLOYEE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
  2  VALUES(200, '2001-JAN-14', '2001-JUN-17', 'AD_ASST', 200);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT LAST_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID, END_DATE, JOB_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID  FROM employees NATURAL JOIN job_history;

LAST_NAME                 DEPARTMENT_ID END_DATE    JOB_ID     EMPLOYEE_ID
------------------------- ------------- ----------- ---------- -----------
Taylor                               80 0031-DEC-06 SA_REP             176
Whalen                              200 2001-JUN-17 AD_ASST            200
```

Comment: I was able to fix it. I have another problem however. How would a natural join work? I am only getting one value in this `SELECT LAST_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID, END_DATE, JOB_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID 
FROM employees
NATURAL JOIN job_history;`

Comment: Can't tell, you never posted sample data for JOB_HISTORY table.

Comment: Oh sorry. `CREATE TABLE job_history
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    START_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    END_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4)
);`

Comment: since you probably need the rest of it as well: 

`INSERT INTO job_history (EMPLOYEE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES(176, '2006-MAR-06', '31-DEC-06', 'SA_REP', 80); 

INSERT INTO employees (EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)  
VALUES(200, 'Whalen', 'justinwhalen@gmail.com', '2001-JUN-17', 'AD_ASST', 200);

INSERT INTO job_history (EMPLOYEE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES(200, '2001-JAN-14', '2001-JUN-17', 'SA_REP', 80); `

Comment: I edited the answer; have a look.

Comment: I see, how would you write in the values then for something like this? Lets say you only wanted just the two values to show, how would you use a common value to show just the ones you want?

Comment: Edited, again. As I said - match all common column's data.

Comment: im not getting the answer from this. I made an error as well. It is 10 for Department ID, not 200.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. You were right. I was off in my values. You have been an amazing help. Thank you for spending your time for me